# Genearating a label dynamically one after another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I want to generate some number of labels programmatically based on the array count .

I found many links for this but couldn't get  proper answer for this . I am trying to generate

these labels inside the for loop . Can any one give me some coding example for my requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
float y = 40;
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, y, 300, 30)];
    [label setText:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    y += 40;
}
```

This gives a simple demonstration of how to generate labels in a loop with their y origin incrementing by 40 each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//generate labels like this
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
//set the frame or add to view or do anything with your label
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc] init];

[arr addObject:lbl];
}

//When you need to use , just iterate through the array and cast the objects back into UILabel
Uilabel *temp;
for(temp in arr){
UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)temp;  
}
```